# Ubuntu Server 20.04 "failed, not found in crypttab..."

Tags: encryption, luks

I have this crypttab:

```
sda1_crypt UUID=25e9b462-c121-4df7-bf18-34ec8f4a12e9 /etc/luks-keys/disk_secret_key luks
```

If I run:

```
cryptdisks_start sda1_crypt
```

I get this error:

```
* Starting crypto disk...
* sda1_crypt (failed, not found in crypttab)...                                          [fail]
```

I've no idea what's wrong.

Comment: checked the UUID?

Comment: blkid /dev/sda1 gives the same UUID

Comment: sorry for poking around, what instructions did you use? what is the output of `ls -la /etc/crypttab` and are you certain, that the keyfile has no newline at the end? --- that's all i can think of for now

Comment: do you have a fitting entry in /etc/fstab